# TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNShare' could not be found

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-share

Hi I am using M1 Apple Chip Macbook Air. I am trying to use react-native-share on a expo based application. I am using expo version 48.0 and react-native-share version 10.0.2 . I am really stuck for couple days now and I appreciate all sorts of help

I tried to solve it by using expo eject and eas build but couldn't solve